# How to download a png file with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I need the user to be able to download png images from my site.  When the mthod runs it completes without errors but no image is downloaded.  I do not need the user to see a pop-up dialog thought it is certainly helpful.  This is what I have right now:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string filename)
        {
            var path = Path.GetFullPath("./wwwroot/images/school-assets/" + filename);
           MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, "image/png", "download");
        }
```

This method is called by an ajax call in the view that looks like this

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "./MyHome/DownloadImage",
            type: "Get",
            data: {filename : filename},
            success: function (file) {
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Edit: 
If i console.log file in the success portion i see a string of bytes so I know it is creating the file but not letting the user get to i.  I have tried content disposition and creating a physical file result as suggested.

Comment: How did you request `DownloadImage`? What do you mean by no image is download.

Answer (score 2):

For `File`, you need to provide the file name with file extension, otherwise, the downloaded file will not be able to open.

Try something like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string filename)
{
    var path = Path.GetFullPath("./wwwroot/images/school-assets/" + filename);
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
    return File(memory, "image/png", Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

Comment: I have made this using an ajax call in the view.  When it runs I can print out the result into the console and see the string of bytes but no image dialog pops up to download it. HEre is the ajax example.
```
function DownloadImage(filename) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "./MyHome/DownloadImage",
            type: "Get",
            data: {filename : filename},
            success: function (file) {
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Caleb If you want to download file by ajax, you need to implement the click event, try to refer [Download excel file with .Net core 2 and EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231215/download-excel-file-with-net-core-2-and-epplus/55234666#55234666)

Comment: Thanks, will try this out when i get to work.  Will give you the answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content dispositon type to enable direct downloading of the file :

```
public IActionResult OnGetPng()
{
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("test.png");

    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "test.png",
        Inline = false
    };

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

    return File(bytes, "image/png");

}
```

If you prefer you can also make use of the `PhysicalFileResult` type which takes care of your stream and return FileResult from your controller. In that case your code looks like this:

```
   var fn = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "test.png");

   var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

   Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();

   return new PhysicalFileResult(fn, "image/jpeg");
```

To get access to the `WebRootPath` you have to inject `IHostingEnvironment env` into your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

@Caleb sir from below code you can download png file.

**Download png file from folder**

```
[HttpGet]
        public FileStreamResult DownloadPngFile(string fileName)
        {            
            var stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot\\images\\school-assets\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open);
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
        }
```

**Download png file from database**

```
   [HttpGet]
            public FileStreamResult DownloadPngFileFromDataBase(string id)
            {
                var _fileUpload = _db.ImageFileUpload.SingleOrDefault(aa => aa.fileid == id);         
                // _fileUpload.FileContent column type is byte
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_fileUpload.FileContent);
                return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
            }
```

For more info please also see this question and answer. [Download Pdf file in asp.net core (accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353719/pdf-file-download-from-byte/57358726#57358726) and one more extra link
[Download files in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486431/return-pdf-to-the-browser-using-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

This code can save photos from URL addresses in the server folder.

```
private readonly Lazy<HttpClient> _client;
```

In constructor:

```
_client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => clientFactory.CreateClient());
```

That is better to use lazy loading in a way the server will not spend additional resources to create HttpClient immediately.

```
public async Task<string> SavePhotoInFolder(string url)
        {
            string photoPath = $"/Photos/{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpeg";

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
            using (
                Stream contentStream = await (await _client.Value.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                stream = new FileStream($"{_appEnvironment.WebRootPath}{photoPath}", FileMode.Create))
            {
                
                await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            return photoPath;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use HttpClient

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
           {  
              try
              {
                using var result = await client.GetAsync($"http://{url}"); 
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {                        
                    return await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }

              }
             catch(Exception ex)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
              }
        }
```